# Как обратится к приватной переменной из другого класса в Java

Tags: java

Например есть код:

```
class B {
    private int i = 22;
}

class A {
    // тут код который выводит переменную i
}
```

Условие:
класс B нельзя менять.
класс А можно менять (т.е наследовать класс B и т.д)

Comment: Обрисуйте, зачем вам так извращаться?

Comment: Тут другой вопрос (принципиальный) встает.

--

**Зачем вообще такие строгости с инкапсуляцией ?**

 Кому надо обойти, все равно обойдет. Только программа непонятней становится.

Comment: Не совсем понял, что вы имели в виду "Кому надо обойти, все равно обойдет" ? Использование reflection взломом не считается, - достаточно посмотреть исходники пакета: он позволяет делать все, кроме того что запрещено (для любого подобного действия java проверяет permissions). По умолчанию все разрешено, - поэтому эти "кулхаки" работают. В апплетах наоборот, многое запрещено. Ни работы с приватными файлами, ни работы с локальной сетью. Чтоб это начало работать, надо задавать permissions отдельно (в обоих случаях).
Или вы имели в виду взлом с редактированием памяти JVM?

Comment: Я к тому, что использовать reflection будет невозможно, если сконфигурированы permissions для приложения.

Comment: Абсолютно не имел в виду какой-то взлом или злонамеренное использование. 

Речь об удобстве использовании кода (библиотек), который вообще-то (при желании) может быть изменен (программистом, вызывающим его) на уровне исходников. 

То, что Java (и другие, знакомые мне системы программирования) действительно удобного доступа к внутренностям объектов не предоставляет, мне известно.

Comment: @jmu
Такие вещи иногда на собеседованиях спрашивают.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Через Reflection

```
    B b = new B();
    Class clazz = B.class;
    Field iField = clazz.getDeclaredField("i");
    iField.setAccessible(true);
    int fieldValue = iField.getInt(b);
    System.out.println("i = " + fieldValue);
```

Comment: а если класс B абстрактный и его инстанс не получить, можно как-нить?

Comment: Через экземпляр класса, который отнаследован от асбстрактного, не? Нет конкретного инстанса - нет данных в объекте - нельзя получить значение. Можно наверно извратиться и создать динамически класс, наследуемый от абстрактного, потом создать инстанс...

Comment: Сорри, замените
Field iField = B.class.getDeclaredField("i");
на
Class clazz = B.class;
Field iField = clazz.getDeclaredField("i");

Comment: да, спсибо.я уже исправил

Comment: а кроме reflection другого способа нет? может быть через сериализацию?(слабо в этом разбираюсь поэтому и спрашиваю)

Comment: Другого документированного способа я не знаю

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, проще в класс А добавить метод

```
public int getI(){
  return i;
}
```

так называемый, `getter`.

Comment: Прочтите вопрос.

    Условие: класс B нельзя менять
С этим условием единственный вариант это reflection.